# Angular HttpClient datasource paginator does not work

Tags: pagination, angular-material

I have the following implementation (Angular 6).

The data is pulled fine and shows in the table as expected. However the paginator doesn't work.

See below:

```
@ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
```

Then in the constructor:

```
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource([]);

    this.requestHttpService.getStuff()
        .subscribe(data => {
            this.results = data;
            this.dataSource = data;
        });
```

Then

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
}
```

And finally in HTML:

```
<mat-paginator #paginator
               [length]="100"
               [pageSize]="10"
               [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]">
</mat-paginator>
```

I am not sure what is wrong with this code but none of those pagination features seem to be working. What am I missing.

Answer (score 1):

Turned out the datasource load had to be initiated from

```
           ngAfterViewInit() {
           }
```

...and the actual paginator assignment has to be wrapped in SetTimeout() function as per suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53013602/matsort-and-matpaginator-does-not-work-without-settimeout/53015635#53015635):

```
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.results);
                this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
            });
```