# Angular 6 mat-table won't sort

Tags: angular, sorting, mat-table

I have an Angular material table with two fields:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort  class="mat-elevation-z8">
   <ng-container matColumnDef="Field1">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Field1</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.Field1}} </td>
   </ng-container>
   <ng-container matColumnDef="Field2">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Field2</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.Field2}} </td>
   </ng-container>
   <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
   <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
</table>
```

I import the following modules:

```
Material.MatTableModule,
Material.MatSortModule,
```

Then I declare the sort as follows:

```
@ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
```

I populate the dataSource from an external API by calling the following method in the constructor:

```
       populateTable() {
            this.requestHttpService.getStuff()
                .subscribe(data => {
                        this.results = data;
                        this.dataSource = this.results;
                        this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
                    },
                    ...
```

As you noticed I'm trying to attach sort after the dataSource is loaded.

I have also tried to attach sort in ngAfterViewInit() and couple of other place but no mater what I do it doesn't work.

Any idea?

Comment: You would need to apply `setTimeout` like `setTimeout(() => {this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;});`. Explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53015635/4868839)

Comment: Just tried it still no joy.

Comment: Please make sure your matColumnDef properties matches with your data model. i.e. your dataSource items should have matching properties. Also, put your matsort in html like <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" #sort="matSort" matSort  class="mat-elevation-z8">

Comment: Raj - if it didn't match the code would throw an error.

Comment: Ah! The other thing that u missed is here `this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.results);`

Comment: What I meant is your displayedColumns should match with your data source properties.

Comment: User3250 - tried that still not working....

Comment: any errors in console?

Comment: That's the thing... not a single error in the console. The table loads up perfectly fine. Both properties are string type... I'm honestly lost with this one...
The only weird thing I noticed is that the     @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort; MatSort is underlined and tells me: Supplied parameters do not match... Parameter selector shpuld have type assignable to (Function\string) but it has type o MatSort...

Comment: Odd! Pls post whole component code after latest changes.

Comment: You using MatSort in ngAfterViewInit right?

Comment: May thanks User3250. I managed to get it to work. Thanks again!

Comment: Cool, `ngAfterViewInit`  and `this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.results);` solved the issue right? Let me answer the question.

Comment: Yes, plus your initial suggestion for setTimeout(() => {this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;});
Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make few changes, move code to `ngAfterViewInit` since `MatSort` is not available till `ngAfterViewInit` and initialize table datasource as below:

```
this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.results);
```